# Connect-AzureAD -Confirm throwing AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'. error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have downloaded powershell azure ad modules and I'm trying to connect to azure ad using below command but it throwing error.

```
Connect-AzureAD -Confirm 

AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'.
```

I have specified correct credentials even then getting above issue .

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/281ffa55-1024-4d39-b83f-a7f184fc4da8/cannot-login-to-azure-portal?forum=AzureAvailabilityZones

Looks like it might be an azure auth issue.

Comment: @John - you will have to wait for Azure to fix the issue. It is being investigated.